# What's the home key for the Android emulator on Mac OS?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using the android emulator without the UI and the keyboard command for "Home" is the Home key but my macbook doesn't have a home key. Does anybody know what the command is?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

in most apps, Fn+Left Cursor works for me

Comment: Thank you very much. Believe it or not this was not an easy thing to find. It's not listed in the documentation either. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling

Answer (score 5):

macbook/single keyboard- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Left Cursor

fullkeyboard - <kbd>Home</kbd> Button

Answer (score 5):

In android emulator cmd + M

You can see it in the options of the emulator

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can find the shortcut keys in Android emulator settings (three dots icon: `...`) > `Help` > `Keyboard shortcuts`. By default, the Home key is mapped to ⇧⌘H